# Replication Issues with MySQL on Windows server 2008 r2 standard edition

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2

I have one Dell Server Intel(R) Xeon(R) 4Cores 16GB 250GB/SATA/RAID5 running MySQL 5.5.28/innodb 45GB of data on Windows server 2008 r2 standard edition.

My situation:

I cant seem to get the Replication Slave IO thread to be just as fast as the SQL thread. The SQL thread catches up to the IO thread so often, while the IO thread always play catch up with the mysql master(installed on

windows server 2003).

With that you get seconds behind master fluctuating between 0 and large number(up to 2000+)

I have ruled out network as a problem. Since I installed 2 instances on same box to replicate from each other (master on port 3308 slave on 3309). And i still experience same issue.

I have done numerous searches on-line and implemented these suggestions and yet non seems to work.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15318 (is an example). I have tweaked the registry and yet no solution.

Please don't say you should use *nix system since I make do with what am provided with.

Kindly let me know what I could be missing. If you need more details to my situation feel free to ask and I will provide.

If you currently run MySQL on Windows server 2008 r2 standard your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With Mysql installed on Windows: Do not play with the following variables:

```
# sync_master_info               = 1
# sync_relay_log                 = 1
# sync_relay_log_info            = 1
# sync_binlog                    = 1
```

Notice they have been commented. They are better left to their default values of 0.

Its been a terrible week trying to figure out why replication slave io thread is always lagging.

Maybe someone might benefit from this info.